# How Can I Bring SQL Data Directly into a Controller in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-duallistbox

As shown below, in the controller.js, I have tried to use the { name: 'item' } style and it worked in the viewer.
However, I would like to pull the data from the SQL Database.
I tried using {{member.member_name}} but it didn't work.

```
$http.get('../crud/members_select.php').then(function(response){
                    $scope.members = response.data;
                });

this.items = [
    { member_name: 'Tim' },
    { member_name: 'Dave' },
    { member_name: 'Jenny' }
];
```

Thus, my question is "How can I do the {{member_name}} thing in order to repeat the data in a single code from SQL Database?"

Below is the HTML CODE.

```
<div class="ibox-content">
   <select ng-options="name as member.member_name for n in members"
   multiple
   ng-model="selections"
   bs-duallistbox></select>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: do you get the expected result if you `console.log(response.data)`?

Comment: try `x.member_name for x in members`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it this way

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example</title>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body ng-app="selectExample">
  <script>
angular.module('selectExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
    { member_name: 'Tim' },
    { member_name: 'Dave' },
    { member_name: 'Jenny' }
  ];
    $scope.selections = [];
  }]);
</script>
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  
  
  <label>Color (null not allowed):
    <select ng-model="selections" ng-options="item.member_name for item in items" multiple></select>
  </label>
  <hr/>
  Currently selected: {{  selections }}

</div>
</body>
</html>
```